# Modifier keys... don't show the "Select keyboard" option

Tags: macos, keyboard, bluetooth, shortcut, keybindings

I'm using keyboard KeyCool 84 with Bluetooth version 4.0. When I use a cable to connect with my Mac (running macOS Mojave 10.14.5), I can use the modifier key function with an option to `Select keyboard`

[image: Modifier keys..]

But when I use Bluetooth to connect, the option to `Select keyboard` doesn't show in the modifier dialog.

Currently I'm using `karabiner-elements` for custom key as a work around.

How can I get this to work with macOS natively?